# SecurityFilterChain Bean doesn't protect app

Tags: java, spring, security, javabeans

I am in the middle of process of mirgation my Spring Security Configuration from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (deprecated) to configuration with beans.

My config class now looks like

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Config {

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

I understand that this configuration doesn't make any behavior settings, but shouldn't it return a SecurityFilterChain bean that will act like the default SecurityFilterChain (as if no configuration was specified)? When I start my app no controllers are secured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add security rules and form for endpoints simply add `.authorizeRequests()` block:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/unprotected", "/endpoints/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Also read [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I marked bean SecurityFilterChain  method as public but it still does't work. I can access my controllers without entering login / password. No login page is generated. But in console I can see generated password for. Only If I remove this SecurityFilterChain bean method from config class, requests are redirected to the login page.

Comment: UPD. Isn't filterChain method supposed to return SecurityFilterChain? What's Config  type?

Comment: @TeaWithoutSugar Sure. Fixed answer